# Connecting Google Domain To Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using [this](https://medium.com/@limichelle21/connecting-google-domains-to-amazon-s3-d0d9da467650) tutorial to use goop.dev google domain to host an AWS S3 bucket.  I followed all of the steps.  I am able to view the S3 Bucket end point, ---s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/awshome in the browser.  After putting in the the cluster of 4 NS-type and the two more records I am unable to view www.goop.dev or goop.dev in the browser.

What else am I missing?

Here is a pic of the DNS

[image]

This is where I am failing.  The redirected endpoint does not resolve.
[image]

Comment: Do you want to use the S3-Protocol on your own URL or do you just want to show a webpage?

Comment: There is no S3- protocol yet.  I want to just show my webpage.  I did use this link and it is not propogating anywhere https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/www.goop.dev  I will wait 30 minutes and if  nothing has propogated I will delete it and do it again.

Comment: I am able to see goop.dev but not www.goop.dev. I think this may related to missing www bucket (as mentioned in comments from medium.com page )

Comment: @AniketChopade I cannot view either goop.dev nor www.goop.dev

Comment: That surely meant your firewall or proxy is blocking your traffic to goop.dev

Comment: I used the howto from AWS and it works: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: @nologin I am following your source.  For some reason my bucket is not coming up as a valid alias in the drop down menu....

Comment: Do you have a picture or more information? Don't understand at which step the problem occurs.

Comment: I added a picture of the DNS.  When I go to www.goop.dev it times out.  I am unable to see the endpoint of the redirected bucket. It may be related to route 53 hosting.

Comment: I added where it stops working.  The redirect does not resolve, the last image in the question.